# Unknown reason of an error while debugging an Opencv project using opencv2 functions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, ffmpeg

I have openCV 2.3 and I am using Visual Studio 2010.

```
    ...
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open("Video.avi");
if( !cap.isOpened() )
{

    puts("***Could not initialize capturing...***\n");
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
} ...
```

This is a code snippet of the while program.
I added a system command in order to hold the output window. I got no errors while building the project but when I began debugging, the output window had this output :

```
warning: Error opening file (../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:477)
***Could not initialize capturing...***

Press any key to continue . . .
```

I checked this directory, the file is available but then why is it that it doesn't open ?
I even have the opencv_ffmpeg.dll in the bin folder with its path added to System Paths.
Still I get this same error ....
I even checked first 3 pages of google search I did but could not find an answer. 
So please help!

---

The error which I mentioned is because, there has been an error in opening the .avi file ...
This is the part of code in cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp -

```
int err = av_open_input_file(&ic, _filename, NULL, 0, NULL);
if (err < 0) {
    CV_WARN("Error opening file"); //Error part
    goto exit_func;
}
```

This file is available at D:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\modules\highgui\src. When I make any changes in this file, they do not reflect on the output window and when I removed this file, even then it did not give any error!:O 
I am not able to understand what is happening ....??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is perhaps a bit confusing. You should read it like this:

```
<severity>: <message> (<where the message originated from>)
```

The message does not tell you, that your program is unable to open the header file, it just informs you that the message was created in that header file.

As you observed correctly, the problem is, that your program cannot find the .avi file. Try supplying the absolute path to that video file:

```
cap.open("C:/absolute/path/to/Video.avi");
```

Comment: I tried what you said ... but still I got the same error!
You can check this [snapshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/86814352/upload.jpg)

Comment: perhaps you need to give the path to the video with backslashes? `cap.open("C:\\absolute\\path\\to\\Video.avi");`

Comment: I tried this but again I am facing that problem .... Is it something else other then the path of the video ??